Is there a way to get a hook modifier or to influence an object on a path but not pull it away from that path

So I am trying to get cube 1 to stay on its path but be pulled into the general direction of cube 2 wherever it may be in 3d space. I also what cube 1's offset factor(data path) to be affected by the location to where cube one is pulled to on path by cube 2 so that it can be plugged into a driver.
What I have tried:
I currently have cube one on a pathing constraint then I have placed a hook modifier on cube 1 to be pulled toward cube 2.
What happens is I start moving cube 2 anywhere and cube 1 gets pulled off the path. Only the origin remains on path and no offset factor change.
I just want cube 1 to stay on its path like a dog on a chain but be pulled toward cube2 all while effecting its offset factor on the constraint.
Is this even possible? thanks in advance.

(Using Blender 4.2.3)

This proposal is a follow-up of Gordon Brinkmann answer, including a driver based on "Cube 1" location.


The blue cube location remains at a constant distance from the empty sphere center labeled "C", while minimizing its distance from the red cube. The green cone Y scale is driven by the blue cube angular position measured from the empty cube labeled "R".
Resources
(Blender 4.2.3+)
Setup

1. An Empty Sphere is used to define the circular trajectory center.
2. The blue "Cube 1" location is imposed by:
2.1. A Copy Location constraint set to transfer only X and Y coordinates from the targeted object, i.e. the red "Cube 2" in the demonstration, leaving its Z position unchanged.
2.2. A Limit Distance constraint set to keep the origin of "Cube 1" on the sphere centered on the "Center" empty, at a distance of 5 m for the demonstration.
3. An Empty Cube is used to define the position from which the "Cube 1" angular position is referenced. The same Limit Distance constraint as at step 2.2 is attached to this object.
Driver
The angular position of "Cube 1", labelled $\alpha$, is computed from the dot product and the cross product of vectors $\vec{CR}$ and $\vec{CM}$, taking advantage that points $C$, $M$ and $R$ are laying in the same constant-Z plane. Indeed,
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\vec{CR} \cdot \vec{CM} & = & \| \vec{CR} \| \| \vec{CM} \| \cos{\alpha} \\
\left( \vec{CR} \times \vec{CM} \right) \cdot \vec{e_Z} & = & \| \vec{CR} \| \| \vec{CM} \| \sin{\alpha} \\
\end{array}
$$
Consequently,
$$
\tan{\alpha} = \frac{\sin{\alpha}}{\cos{\alpha}} = \frac{(x_R-x_C)(y_M-y_C)-(y_R-y_C)(x_M-x_C)}
{(x_R-x_C)(x_M-x_C)+(y_R-y_C)(y_M-y_C)}
$$

4. The driver is attached to the Y Scale property of the green cone for the demonstration.
5. The output Scripted Expression is returning $\tan^{-1}\alpha/\pi \in [-1;1]$.
Side notes

A simpler driver expression can be used based on the Rotational Distance between two bones, instead of the Transform Channel of points $C$, $M$ and $R$, with Copy Location and Locked Track constraints attached to the bones. However the returned angle is unsigned.
As mentioned by Gordon Brinkmann, using a GeometryNodes modifier could alleviate the whole setup. Furthermore it is suited for non circular trajectories.


For a simple circle path this is quite easy: put a Copy Location constraint on Cube 1 and a Limit Distance constraint (the order is important, first Copy then Limit).
In the Copy Location constraint you choose Cube 2 as Target. For the Limit Distance constraint I added an Empty to the world's center as Target. Then I set a Distance of for example 5 m and set Clamp Region to On Surface. This way Cube 1 can never get further or closer of the Empty.

Now moving Cube 2 (red) around Cube 1 (blue) will make the blue one trying to reach the location of the red one, but it is limited to a circle of 5 m around the Empty. The circle itself is only for visualization, the path is not needed.

Note that this is a top down view and the red Cube 2 only moves in the XY plane. The Limit Distance constraint however works 3-dimensional, so if the red Cube 2 will be moved up or down, the blue Cube 1 will not stay on the 2D circle path. It will be able to move spherically around the Empty.
If you want it to always stay at Z = 0 for example, you have to add another constraint: the Limit Location constraint, where you enable the Z axis for Minimum and Maximum and set them both to 0 (or any other height you want).
Very important: to make this work correctly, the order has to be:

Copy Location
Limit Location
Limit Distance

Any other order will not give the correct result.


Thank you, you Virtuoso! This is the exact movement  I am looking for only Is there a way to put a custom property on cube 1 so I can make a driver based on location of cube 1's location on the path?

Which "location" of cube 1 are you interested in ? Its angular position along the circle ?

Pretty much it's angular position on the circle almost like the data path based on the where it is on that path from 0 - 1

@Maddoghen Well, I have no good idea for a driver, but instead of using an Empty as center, I could take a mesh object and give it a Geometry Nodes modifier, then calculate the factor of the cube's position on a hypothetical circle around the origin of the GN object. It all depends on what you want to do with it further. Instead of constraints this could all be created in Geometry Nodes. But for the initial basic function to make a cube follow another cube while staying on a circle this was not necessary.
